# grid lines in Manipulate plots are not showing up when first rendered?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have a `Manipulate` within which the plot does not render completely initially:

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 If [ bRefreshPlot, (
     plot = ParametricPlot3D[ {u, v, u^2 + av (-1)^fn v^2}, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1} ] ;
   bRefreshPlot = False )
  , ] ;
 plot
 , Grid[{
   { Slider[ Dynamic[av, ( av = # ; bRefreshPlot = True ; tick = Not[tick]) &] , {0.05, 2} ], Dynamic@av },
   { SetterBar[Dynamic[fn, ( fn = # ; bRefreshPlot = True ; tick = Not[tick]) &] , Range[2] ] }
 }]
 , {{tick, False}, None}
 , {{av, 1}, None}
 , {{bRefreshPlot, True}, None}
 , {plot, None}
 , {{fn, 2}, None}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 , ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

Initially, the `Manipulate` output looks like:

[image: initially]

but after clicking each of the `SetterBar` buttons in sequence (toggling from paraboloid to saddle and back), the grid lines then show up as in:

[image: with grid lines]

I appear to be able to use '`SaveDefinitions` -> True' to work around the initial display oddity.  However, this lack of grid lines also occurs after adjusting the slider.  After an adjustment of the slider, the plot is first rendered without grid lines, but after doing the same two-click toggle of the `SetterBar` buttons, the plot shows up properly with the grid lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` to the plot.

```
Manipulate[tick;
 If[bRefreshPlot, (plot = 
    ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, u^2 + av (-1)^fn v^2}, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
                     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];  bRefreshPlot = False),];
   plot, Grid[{{Slider[
     Dynamic[av, (av = #; bRefreshPlot = True;  tick = Not[tick]) &], {0.05, 2}], 
    Dynamic@av}, {SetterBar[ Dynamic[fn, (fn = #; bRefreshPlot = True; tick = Not[tick]) &], 
     Range[2]]}}], {{tick, False}, None}, {{av, 1}, 
  None}, {{bRefreshPlot, True}, None}, {plot, None}, {{fn, 2}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Or "Mesh->True"...

Comment: Just to lower the "unanswered pire"